# ffmpeg script - slicing a video into multiple slices

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

I am currently using ffmpeg to slice video files. I automated the process through a script called `ffmpeg_split.sh`. To view the script click [here](https://gist.github.com/hfossli/5996260). When I run the script I have an error when trying to get the `parse_duration_info()`. In other words, the issue is trying to set the time length of the video slices. The error thrown is `Bad input to parse_duration_info()`

Here is the syntax to slice a video with script: `ffmpeg_split.sh -s test_vid.mp4 -o video-part%03d.mp4 -c 00:00:08`

```
Flags: 
-s  Path to video source (string)

-o  Path to output file with format (string)
    Format must be printf-like, for example ./path/video-part-%03d.avi

-c  Chunk length in seconds (integer)
```

Issue is below: [Here's the full script](https://gist.github.com/hfossli/5996260)

```bsh
function parse_duration_info() {
    if [[ $1 ]] && [[ $2 -gt 0 ]] && [[ $2 -lt 5 ]] ; then
        __OFFSET=$2
        __DURATION_PATTERN='\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\):\([0-9][0-9]\)\.\([0-9][0-9]\)'
        echo "$1" | sed "s/$__DURATION_PATTERN/\\$__OFFSET/"
    else
        echo "Bad input to parse_duration_info()"
        echo "Givven duration $1"
        echo "Givven offset $2"
        echo "Exiting..."
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to dissect this script a bit to see why it's failing. This isn't that hard a task, since you have the source code to it already. I'd start with confirming that the commands in the function implementation, `get_video_duration_in_seconds_from_file()` is correct. Specifically when I ran this command on a few `.mp4` files I had, it would return nothing:

```
__DURATION_HMS=$(ffmpeg -i "$__FILE" 2>&1 | grep Duration | \
    grep '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d' -o)
```

**NOTE:** This is line #54.

So without this value, this would be a good reason why the calls that come after it to the function `parse_duration_info()` are returning the error message.

According to the comments in the original script, there should be 2 arguments to `parse_duration_info()`.

```
# arg1: duration in format 01:23:45.67
# arg2: offset for group 1 gives hours, 2 gives minutes, 
#       3 gives seconds, 4 gives milliseconds
```

#### More debugging output

Additionally you can enable more verbose output of this script by add this line just after the shebang (`#!/bin/bash`).

```
set +x
```

If enabling full verbosity on the entire script to too much you can selectively enable it around certain blocks of code like so:

```
parse_duration_info() {
    set +x

    ... body of function ...

    set -x
}
```

Comment: Ok i am new to scripting but I am having difficulties figuring it out: What do you mean it is missing value `__DURATION_HMS`?

Comment: I tried doing this instead for the duration `ffmpeg -i "$__FILE" 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,`

Comment: Running this code returns nothing: `ffmpeg -i "$__FILE" 2>&1 | grep Duration | grep '\d\d:\d\d:\d\d.\d\d' -o`. Change `"$__FILE"` to `"my.mp4"` and run it in the shell.

Comment: `$__File` to `test_vid.mp4` worked. So that means the value of that variable is not being set to the path of the input video?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student - you have to do more debugging, that just tells you that that line of code is working OK. I'd echo out `$1` and `$2` to the parse function to confirm that they have values being properly passed in.

Comment: i have echo the values and nothing shows. I have dissected the script but have no luck in coming up with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`__DURATION_HMS=$(ffmpeg -i "${FILE}" 2>&1 | grep Duration | \
   grep -e '[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}' -o)`

Comment: A bit of explanation would be nice.